# MFC ribbon large images resource on multiple rows

Tags: mfc, icons, ribbon

I'm working on a ribbon application and I need lots of icons for each category. If I put all the images for the category on the same row it becomes too wide, i.e. difficult for maintainance when I need to add/edit something. So my question is: is there a way to put the images on several rows? Thanks!

Comment: One more thing - is this actually the only way to apply icons to the buttons? Is it possible to set individual icons for each button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to put images on several rows.
The toolbar mode to manipulate tiles of the bitmaps isn't available on demand.

I use a different tool to manage such bitmaps (i.E. [Axialis](http://www.axialis.com))

Answer (score 0):

Axialis Icon Workshop is a good choice. Try to get the free version somewhere: It has everything you need for ribbon icons, including good alpha channel handling.

If you really insist on using smaller bitmaps, you could use an alternative constructor to associate icons to your UI elements:

```
CMFCToolBarImages smallerIconGroup;    // load some bitmap ressource into this object
...
CMFCRibbonButtonEx myButton = new CMFCRibbonButtonEx(ID_MYCOMMAND, _T("My Button"), smallerIconGroup.ExtractIcon(0));
```

Comment: By "small" you mean 16px? Or can it also be done with 32px images?

Comment: Or you mean a few icons in one group?

Comment: Yes, a few icons in a group.

Comment: I don't have the needed reputation XD

Answer (score 0):

OK, I saw Axialis. It looks good, but for now I'm sticking to Gimp :D If I see the icons are too much, I'll check the portable version.